# iPhone and iPad Rich Text Editor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, richtext

I need to create a rich text editor (for text alignment, fonts, text and background colours, bold, italics, underlining etc) for an iPhone and iPad app. How should I accomplish. I have heard of storing the data as HTML and rendering it in a UIWebView, but how can I allow the user to edit the data without having to interact with the HTML source?

Answer (score 1):

Go into the style part of [Three20 UI](http://three20.info/overview#UI). It may be what you need for. I don't know if it is a overkill for a starter, but you may try